# Query Find All WooCommerce Categories: Unassign All Products From All Categories

Tags: woocommerce

I am struggling to figure out the fastest way to unassign all WooC categories from each product so that I can then delete all existing categories and rebuild using new category names without deleting or otherwise harming any existing product?

Comment: It should be fine to delete the category without removing the products.

Comment: Shout out to DoubleSharp --- I want to thank you for your prompt response. Several years ago I posed a similar question and when I acted to delete the existing categories every product disappeared too. 

Please be so kind to qualify your guidance. Does your word "should" mean most likely or a tenative maybe?

Comment: In a vanilla install of WooCommerce deleting a category will not remove the products.